# Filter_input e PDO

Tags: php, pdo

1 - Qual filtro seria mais util em uma string que depois será colocado em um BD.
2 - Existe alguma página que mostra o que cada filtro trata e quais seus principais usos? Porque só achei a página https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/filter.constants.php que cita todos os filtros, mas não diz quando usar cada um.